# Getting Zigbee device info from node-red-contrib-tasmota JSON

Tags: json, node-red, tasmota

I'm just getting started with Tasmota on a Sonarr Zigbee Bridge and trying to interpret the data it spits out. Here's an example:

```
{
  "ZbReceived": {
    "0x11FE": {
      "Device": "0x11FE",
      "Name": "DoorContact",
      "Power": 1,
      "Endpoint": 1,
      "LinkQuality": 147
    }
  }
}
```

How do I address the info in here, without knowing/using the device number("0x11Fe") - for example, I want to get the device name, power setting, etc.

I was hoping I could do something like ZbReceived[1].Name, but that doesn't work.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the `Object.keys()` function ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys))

```
var devices = Object.keys(msg.payload);
var name = msg.payload[devices[0]].Name;
var power = msg.payload[devices[0]].Power;
```

`Object.keys(obj)` returns and array of all the keys into the JSON object (one layer deep) so since we know that there is only one key in the `msg.payload` we can access it in slot 0 (arrays are always indexed from 0).